# running fabric script locally

Tags: django, fabric

I have a django app and I wrote a fabric script that installs my app on deployment server (Cent OS 5).

Now I want to run the same fabric script locally on the deployment server.

Is there a way to do it without supplying ssh user and password?

I mean just with "-H localhost"?

Thanks, Alex A.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes, you can run fab locally by using method **local** instead of **run**. What I do typically is have methods for setting up the environment, and call these methods first before calling the actual task. Let me illustrate this with an example for your specific question

### **fabfile.py**

```
    from fabric.operations import local as lrun, run
    from fabric.api import task
    from fabric.state import env

    @task
    def localhost():
        env.run = lrun
        env.hosts = ['localhost']

    @task
    def remote():
        env.run = run
        env.hosts = ['some.remote.host']

    @task
    def install():
        env.run('deploymentcmd')
```

And based on the environment, you can do the following

Install on localhost:

```
    fab localhost install
```

Install on remote machine:

```
    fab remote install
```

Answer (score 7):

I am using another trick for executing remote task locally:

```
from fabric.api import run, sudo, local
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def locally():
    global run
    global sudo
    global local
    _run, _sudo = run, sudo
    run = sudo = local
    yield
    run, sudo = _run, _sudo

def local_task():
    with locally():
        run("ls -la")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very elegant, the only drawback to seems to be the fact that your sudo just becomes local and you can't do sudo locally.

That can be achieved with a tiny modification:


```python
    sudo = lambda cmd: local('sudo ' + cmd)
```

Answer (score 4):

Slightly less elegant than [Varun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769071/543431), but maybe more practical by defaulting to run on the local machine unless another environment selector is given.

```
from fabric.api import *

# default to running on localhost
env.hosts = ["localhost"]

DEPLOYMENT_PATH = "/some/path/{}/"

def local_or_remote(*args, **kwargs):
    func = local if env.host == "localhost" else run
    return func(*args, **kwargs)


@task
def live():
    """
    Select live environment
    """
    env.hosts = ["host1", "host2"]
    env.path = DEPLOYMENT_PATH.format("live")


@task
def beta():
    """
    Select beta environment
    """
    env.hosts = ["host1", "host2"]
    env.path = DEPLOYMENT_PATH.format("beta")


@task
def host_info():
    local_or_remote("uname -a")
```

Then run locally as:

```
fab host_info
```

or remotely with:

```
fab live host_info
```

PS. Here is the [Github issue](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/98) on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you can ssh into your localhost without a password:

`$ ssh-copy-id localhost`

And then just run it as you said, with the `-H localhost` command line option

Answer (score 2):

You can run ssh server on your local machine to be able to ssh to localhost. And then just run scripts with "-H localhost". Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of [Varun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769071/543431) that takes into account local not capturing stdout/stderr.  Without specifying capture=True you would not be able to get results from local.

```
from fabric.operations import local, run
from fabric.api import task
from fabric.state import env

def local_run(*args):
    return local(args[0], capture=True)

@task
def localhost():
    env.run = local_run
    env.hosts = ['localhost']

@task
def remote():
    env.run = run
    env.hosts = ['some.remote.host']

@task
def install():
    env.run('deploymentcmd')
```